Ballistic curve in 3D space with launch offsets
I'm looking for the direction $\vec{d}$ to hit a target $\vec{T}$ in 3D space, launching from a point $\vec{P}$ with speed $s$, but with some additional constraints. It's assumed that $\vec{d}$ is a unit vector, $||\vec{d}||=1$.
I think it's helpful to write the formula for the most basic case down, and 'evolve' it to express the constraints.
$$\vec{P}+st\vec{d}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2 = \vec{T}$$
The gravity $\vec{g}$ and speed $s$ are known.
Now come in three constraints, which make this problem extremely hard (thus, this question).
1: We're shooting from a barrel (which will be pointed exactly in the direction $\vec{d}$) that has the length $r_2$, which is known. The formula changes:
$$\vec{P}+r_2\vec{d}+ st\vec{d}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2 =\vec{T}$$
2: The barrel does not originate at $\vec{P}$. Instead, it is mounted on a turret that sits at $\vec{P}$. The barrel itself can only do up-down movement, the left-right comes from the rotation of the turret.

The origin $\vec{B}$ of the barrel can be assumed to be on the 'side' of $\vec{P}$, such that $(\vec{B}-\vec{P})\cdot\vec{d} = 0$ holds. We set $\vec{b}=\vec{B}-\vec{P}$. The offset $r_1$ to this side, which is $||\vec{b}||$, is known.
We set the launch position $\vec{L}=\vec{P}+\vec{b} + r_2\vec{d}$. The formula changes:
$$||\vec{b}||=r_1\\
\vec{b}\cdot\vec{d}=0\\
\vec{L}=\vec{P}+ \vec{b} + r_2\vec{d}\\
\vec{L}+ st\vec{d}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2 = \vec{T}$$
Because the up-down and left-right are independent, we are now no longer looking for just $\vec{d}$, but also $\vec{b}$, which together solve the equation(s).
3: The tank (and thus the turret) may be angled arbitrarily. Its up vector, around which the turret rotates, is known: $\vec{n}$.
The relation of the turret and the barrel is that of two circles, where the 'first' is perpendicular to $\vec{n}$ with radius $r_1$, the second perpendicular to $\vec{b}$ with radius $r_2$.

Next, after the bullet leaves the barrel at $\vec{L}$, it will only be affected by gravity $\vec{g}$, which means that its flight path will be on a plane. This plane must include $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{T}$ (launch and target), as well as be coplanar to $\vec{g}$ AND $\vec{d}$ (because the bullet launches in $\vec{d}$).
Putting it all together:

Express direction as unit vector: $$||\vec{d}||=1$$
Turret rotates around $\vec{n}$: $$\vec{n}\cdot\vec{b}=0$$
Barrel only does up-down, has an offset of $r_1$ from $\vec{P}$: $$\vec{b}\cdot\vec{d}=0\\
||\vec{b}||=r_1$$
Physics equation:
$$\vec{L}=\vec{P}+ \vec{b} + r_2\vec{d}\\
\vec{L}+ st\vec{d}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2 = \vec{T}$$
All on a plane ($\vec{B}$ and $\vec{L}$ are equivalent for this equation, since $\vec{B}+r_2\vec{d}=\vec{L}$ and the plane contains $\vec{d}$):
$$\vec{d}\cdot((\vec{T}-\vec{L})\times\vec{g})=0\\
or\\
\vec{d}\cdot((\vec{T}-\vec{B})\times\vec{g})=0\\
or\\
(\vec{g}\times\vec{d})\cdot(\vec{T}-\vec{L})=0\\
or\\
(\vec{g}\times\vec{d})\cdot(\vec{T}-\vec{B})=0$$


Now, this was a lot, just to explain the formulas I ended up with.
It's probably a good idea to start with the following two operations:

Shift everything to the origin, so $\vec{P}$ disappears.
Rotate everything, so $\vec{n}$ point up: $n_x=n_y=0 \implies b_z=0$. This will mean that $\vec{g}$ no longer points down.

I assume that there exist two solutions for $\vec{b}$, and for every $\vec{b}$, two more solutions for $\vec{d}$ - so four in total.
The solution will probably involve going down to ${g_x,g_y,g_z}$ levels, that is, look at the individual values, because of the cross product in there.
But this is really as far as I've gotten.

a point of pedantry: I think your equations would be easier on the eyes (and brain) if you changed the affine points $P$ and $T$ in vectors (w.r.t. an arbitrary origin $O$) via $\vec P \equiv P - O$ and so on. Also, reserve "cdot" for the inner product, i.e. replace $s\cdot t \cdot \vec d$ with $st\vec d$ and so on.

You mean, just change every $P$ to $\vec{P}$, same for other points?

I think that you can simplify this a bit if you take muzzle velocity as a given parameter. Then you don't really have to constantly keep track of the trajectory between P and the end of the barrel

Well, the muzzle velocity is just $\vec{v}=s\vec{d}$. It's interchangeable.

@ThomasB. But is it a significant difference if the motion starts  at $s$ or $s\cos\theta$, if you see what I mean?

Sorry, no, I don't follow. $s$ is a fixed value, and it is known. It is the same regardless of the direction $\vec{d}$ we're firing.

@ThomasB. It's ok I haven't been very clear. My question is this: usually in classic problems involving projectiles that are of the sort "Find the angle $\theta$ to shoot at given speed $v_0$ to hit target a distance $D$ away.." , we make the assumption that varying the angle does not change the distance $D$. This is also a good approximation often in practice, since no real object exists at a mathematical point anyway, we neglect the change in $D$ that's due to us varying the projection angle $\theta$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

How do you seek to use this?  I ask because the perturbation of the barrel movement and length should be trivially small unless targeting something very close.  Solving the simplified equation you started from as an initial guess, and then using a root solver would be very effective if you can use a root solver.  If you need a closed-form analytic solution, it may be harder.

Also, this is trivially reducible to the 2d case, because for any given target position, there is one and only one turret rotation which puts the bullet in the plane of the target (well, 2... 180 degrees apart).  Thus you can pre-compute that part first, and then bake any 3d effects (such as the barrel not being in-line with the center of rotation) into the 2d problem.

It'll be for a game that I'm working on, where I need to figure out how to orient a barrel such that the tank will precisely hit what the player aims at.
I don't think you can easily reduce this to 2D. If you rotate this entire system to make $\vec{n}$ point 'up', gravity will no longer point 'down'.

@ThomasB. actually, it occurs to me that since indeed gravity has components which are not in the B-L-T plane, you can't guarantee the projectile's motion remains in that plane, no?

Yes, this is why the last equation (the plane one) is there. We're trying to find a solution in which the gravity is in the B-L-T plane.

I do mean change $P$ to $\vec P$. Points aren't vectors, and vectors aren't points. See: The First (Second) Fundamental Problem of Geodesy and also "Affine space vs. Vector Space".

It is indeed useful here to shift the coordinate system origin's to $\vec{P}$, via a simple translation, mainly so that the equations look a bit nicer. So everywhere in this post I assume $\vec{P}=(0,0,0)$, which won't add any complication later as we'll see.
 Parameterizing $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ via two angles 
Now firstly, it turns out that we can express the barrel vector $\vec{b}$ as a function of a single angle $\alpha$, given the orientation unit vector $\vec{n}=(n_x,n_y,n_z)$:
$$ \vec{b}=\frac{r_1}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}n_x n_z \cos\alpha -n_y\sin\alpha \\ n_y n_z \cos\alpha + n_x \sin\alpha \\
-(n_x^2+n_y^2)\cos\alpha \end{pmatrix}, $$
note that this expression will be undefined for the special case of completely horizontal orientation of the turret: $n_z=1,n_x=n_y=0$. However, programmatically you can easily address that, either by a special condition or by ensuring that this specific edge case is never possible. You can always simply cap $n_z$ at $0.999$ or something similar to that, for all practical purposes it will simulate a horizontal orientation. Maybe there's a parameterization that avoids that small issue, but it's no big deal.
Now, exactly the same method can be applied to parameterize $\vec{d}$, the cannon vector, as a function of a second angle $\beta$, so that it rotates around $\vec{b}$:
$$ \vec{d}=\frac{r_2}{r_1\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}b_x b_z \cos\beta -r_1 b_y\sin\beta \\ b_y b_z \cos\beta + r_1 b_x \sin\beta \\
-(b_x^2+b_y^2)\cos\beta \end{pmatrix}, $$
Note that my $\vec{d}$ is different to yours because it's not normalized, but has a magnitude $r_2$, similar to $\vec{b}$ having magnitude $r_1$.
There are several benefits to doing that. First, note that we have eliminated the two "simpler" perpendicularity conditions:
$$ \vec{d}\cdot\vec{b}=0\\  \vec{n}\cdot\vec{b}=0, $$
because they are already satisfied by writing the vectors in this form (as you can verify).
Secondly, since this is for a game, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are convenient parameters to control the movement of the turret and the barrel. When you do that, you in fact no longer need to care about the translation of the origin to $\vec{P}$ at all, because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not affected by it, yet as we'll now demonstrate, our solutions (if they exist) are uniquely determined by both of these angles alone.
 Counting equations and variables (updated) 
At any rate, we are left with only two equations that require solving, the plane one:
$$\left((\vec{T}-\vec{b})\times\vec{g}\right)\cdot \vec{d} = 0, \tag{1}$$
where note that after the translation of the origin, $\vec{B} \rightarrow \vec{b}$; and a second vector equation for the trajectory:
$$ \vec{b} + \vec{d} + v_0 t\hat{d}+ \frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2 = \vec{T}, \tag{2} $$
where $\hat{d} = \large\frac{\vec{d}}{\big|\big|\vec{d}\big|\big|}$.
But, it turns out that equation $(1)$ is in fact a consequence of $(2)$! To see this rewrite $(2)$ as:
$$\vec{T}-\vec{b} = \vec{d} + v_0 t\hat{d}+ \frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2,$$
where we have just subtracted $\vec{b}$ from both sides. Now, take the cross product of both sides with $\vec{g}$:
$$ (\vec{T}-\vec{b}) \times \vec{g} = \left(\vec{d} + v_0 t\hat{d}+ \frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2\right)\times\vec{g} ,$$
and note that on the RHS, the last term cancels out due to $\vec{g}\times\vec{g}=\vec{0}$:
$$ (\vec{T}-\vec{b}) \times \vec{g} = \vec{d}\times\vec{g} + (v_0 t\hat{d})\times\vec{g}+ \require{cancel}\cancel{\left(\frac{1}{2}\vec{g}t^2\right)\times\vec{g}},$$
finally, take the dot product of both sides with $\vec{d}$ which brings us to the exact form of $(1)$:
$$\left((\vec{T}-\vec{b})\times\vec{g}\right)\cdot \vec{d} = (\vec{d}\times\vec{g})\cdot\vec{d} + ((v_0 t\hat{d})\times\vec{g})\cdot\vec{d} = 0, $$
and it's clear that both remaining terms also vanish because both $\vec{d}\times\vec{g}$ and $\hat{d}\times\vec{g}$ are perpendicular to $\vec{d}$, by property of the cross product. So we see that condition $(1)$ is satisfied by virtue of the kinematic vector equation $(2)$, and therefore it is not really an additional constraint.
So we have three equations in three variables $\alpha, \beta$ and $t$.
However, the equations involve trigonometric functions in $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and also a square factor in $t$. Therefore a unique solution should not be expected to exist here. To get an intuition about why, note that for every $\alpha$ there is a unique $\beta$ that "captures" the target so that it is in the plane spanned by the cannon vector $\vec{d}$ and the gravity vector $\vec{g}$. This is because for a fixed $\alpha$, varying $\beta$ then means "sweeping" this plane over the entire 3D space, and one of these will include the target point.
(in fact there are two planes that will coincide with the target because that "sweeping" rotation is by $2\pi$, hence it sweeps said plane onto every point in 3D space twice. But, one of these will always be such that the barrel is facing in the generally opposite direction to the target).
Now note, that for each of these possibilities, our fixed muzzle velocity $v_0$ (called $s$ in your post) may not be sufficient to actually hit the target, or it may be in fact too large to hit it and hence will "overshoot", depending on the case.
So we see that there won't of course be a real and positive solution $t$ for the trajectory of the shell for each $\alpha$ and $\beta$ combination that puts the target in the plane of $\vec{g}$ and $\vec{d}$.
What generally happens then, intuitively speaking, is that when $v_0$ is large enough, where "large" just means in proportion to the effect of gravity and the distance of the target, we'll get several solutions. If it is too small, or the target is too far, there may be no solutions. If it is an in-between case, there may even be cases in which there is a unique solution.
 Examples of numerical solution methods (updated) 
With all that in mind, I thought it would be nice to show an example, written in Python, that solves it for a certain starting configuration via using the least_squares method from the scipy library:
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
# --Parameters--
# 1. Turret orientation normal
nx = 0.364
ny = 0.543
nz =  sqrt(1-nx**2-ny**2)

# 2. Target position coordinates (relative to shifted origin so P=(0,0,0))
Tx = 2
Ty = -3
Tz = 3.5

# 3. Offset sizes 
r1 = 2
r2 = 2.5

# Muzzle velocity
v0=9

# Gravitational constant
g=9.81

# Normalization factor to make equations shorter
r1n = r1/sqrt(nx**2+ny**2)

# Define the system of equations
def f(variables):
    bx, by, bz, dx, dy, dz, A, B, t = variables
    r=np.zeros(9)
    r[0] = r1n*(nx*nz*cos(A)-ny*sin(A))-bx
    r[1] = r1n*(ny*nz*cos(A)+nx*sin(A))-by
    r[2] = -r1n*(nx**2+ny**2)*cos(A)-bz
    r[3] = (r2/(r1*sqrt(bx**2+by**2)))*(bx*bz*cos(B)-r1*by*sin(B))-dx
    r[4] = (r2/(r1*sqrt(bx**2+by**2)))*(by*bz*cos(B)+r1*bx*sin(B))-dy
    r[5] = (-r2/(r1*sqrt(bx**2+by**2)))*(bx**2+by**2)*cos(B)-dz
    r[6] = bx+dx+v0*dx*t/r2-Tx
    r[7] = by+dy+v0*dy*t/r2-Ty
    r[8] = bz+dz+v0*dz*t/r2-(g*t**2)/2-Tz
    return r

# Print a solution, given the following turret and barrel positions and angles:
B_X = 0.00030780763
B_Y = -1.6256520047
B_Z = 1.1650090493
D_X = -1.1489204712
D_Y = 1.2919313983
D_Z = 1.8057948424
Alpha = 3.6127
Beta = 3.61799927
T = 0
result = least_squares(f, [B_X,B_Y,B_Z,D_X,D_Y,D_Z,Alpha,Beta,T])
print (f"Solution\n"
       f"========\n" 
       f"b=({result.x[0]},{result.x[1]},{result.x[2]})\n"
       f"d=({result.x[3]},{result.x[4]},{result.x[5]})\n"
       f"α={result.x[6]}, β={result.x[7]}, t={result.x[8]}\n")

You can run the above code via this SageCell Permalink.
The reason you see more than $3$ equations in this code, is simply because I didn't want the equations to get extremely messy, so I added an extra equation for each component of $\vec{b}$, which simply defines them in terms of $\alpha$ (A in the code), and similarly with respect to $\vec{d}$. Rest assured, this is still just the kinematic equation $(2)$, albeit written in a different form. The format here is that each equation (in the code: r[0],r[1],..,r[8]) is taken as an expression that's equated to zero, which is why all the terms are on the same side.
To test whether the result is correct, I also created a Geogebra sheet you can interact with, here. Following is a screenshot that corresponds to the specific parameters given in the above code, before (left) and after (right) solving:

What I did was to give the initial values that correspond to the left picture as n_x,n_y,n_z,B_X,B_Y,B_Z,D_X,D_Y,D_Z,A,B,v0, etc. as you can see in the code. Then having obtained the solution from the program, it includes among other things $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which are easy to set in Geogebra to immediately verify the result, as you see was done in the right side of the screenshot.
The tilted brown (nearly transparent) plane is the orientation of the turret, while the blue plane is the plane that contains the current trajectory of a fired projectile (from the green vector which is $\vec{d}$). The least_squares method seems adequately suited for this type of problem because it accepts a "guess" as a parameter, as you can see above. For example, it can be particularly useful in the context of the game to put different starting values for $t$ in certain situations, for example, if you know you need to shoot over a high mountain range to get to the target, look for solutions who take longer amount of time (that you can estimate the minimum for, by other means). Then pass $t$ accordingly to least_squares, along with the other parameters representing the current position of the turret and barrel, and it will take that as the starting point in searching a solution.
One implementation detail that's important here, is that this function may not always return a correct solution. The most straightforward way to verify the solution then, would be to programmatically substitute the outputs $\vec{b},\vec{d},t$ in $(2)$ and check that the shell gets within a certain acceptable threshold of the target point.
You will probably want to read more about the least_squares method and possibly compare its efficiency with other related techniques, as I certainly confess to being no expert with regards to numerically solving such systems of equations. The above code is based on very preliminary research I did on that numerical aspect of the question, just to see if a solution is obtainable by such a method.
Update: since this turns out not to be an overdetermined problem, there is an additional way to solve it. Namely via using the fsolve method, which only works if the number of equations is equal to the number of variables. Here's the example code and the corresponding SageCell permalink (It uses the same parameters as the original version):
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import warnings

# Suppress annoying warning that outputs to the console sometimes when running fsolve 
# (should probably understand its meaning more deeply if you're going to make use of this code)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'The iteration is not making good progress')

# --Parameters--
# 1. Turret orientation normal
nx = 0.364
ny = 0.543
nz =  sqrt(1-nx**2-ny**2)

# 2. Target position coordinates (relative to shifted origin so P=(0,0,0))
Tx = 2
Ty = -3
Tz = 3.5

# 3. Offset sizes 
r1 = 2
r2 = 2.5

# Muzzle velocity
v0=9

# Gravitational constant
g=9.81

# Normalization factor to make equations shorter
r1n = r1/sqrt(nx**2+ny**2)

# Define the system of equations
def f(variables):
    bx, by, bz, dx, dy, dz, A, B, t = variables
    r=np.zeros(9)
    r[0] = r1n*(nx*nz*cos(A)-ny*sin(A))-bx
    r[1] = r1n*(ny*nz*cos(A)+nx*sin(A))-by
    r[2] = -r1n*(nx**2+ny**2)*cos(A)-bz
    r[3] = (r2/(r1*sqrt(bx**2+by**2)))*(bx*bz*cos(B)-r1*by*sin(B))-dx
    r[4] = (r2/(r1*sqrt(bx**2+by**2)))*(by*bz*cos(B)+r1*bx*sin(B))-dy
    r[5] = (-r2/(r1*sqrt(bx**2+by**2)))*(bx**2+by**2)*cos(B)-dz
    r[6] = bx+dx+v0*dx*t/r2-Tx
    r[7] = by+dy+v0*dy*t/r2-Ty
    r[8] = bz+dz+v0*dz*t/r2-(g*t**2)/2-Tz
    return r

# Here we want to demonstrate fsolve can also find multiple solutions, so we iterate over a few alpha,beta and t combinations
# to take them as starting "guesses" for fsolve, and that way we find several (duplicate solutions may come up but we later filter them out).
Alpha = 0
Beta = 0
sols = []
T = 0
for i in range(6):
    Alpha = i
    for j in range(6):
        Beta = j
        B_X=r1n*(nx*nz*cos(Alpha)+ny*sin(Alpha))
        B_Y=r1n*(ny*nz*cos(Alpha)-nx*sin(Alpha))
        B_Z=-r1n*(nx**2+ny**2)*cos(Alpha)
        D_X = (r2/(r1*sqrt(B_X**2+B_Y**2)))*(B_X*B_Z*cos(Beta)-r1*B_Y*sin(Beta))
        D_Y = (r2/(r1*sqrt(B_X**2+B_Y**2)))*(B_Y*B_Z*cos(Beta)+r1*B_X*sin(Beta))
        D_Z = (-r2/(r1*sqrt(B_X**2+B_Y**2)))*(B_X**2+B_Y**2)*cos(Beta)
        for k in range(2):   
            result = fsolve(f, [B_X,B_Y,B_Z,D_X,D_Y,D_Z,Alpha,Beta,T])
            
            # "Sanity check" the candidate solution, t > 0 and $|b|$ is close enough to r1. More conditions can be added.
            if result[8] > 0 and abs(result[0]**2+result[1]**2+result[2]**2-r1**2) < 10**(-8):
                sols.append(result.tolist())
            T = T + 1
            
# Filter out duplicate solutions (note we use "isclose" to check if two floats are "equal", no other option here).
solsNoDup = []
for sl in sorted(sols):
    if all(not(isclose(sl[0],a,rel_tol=10**(-6)) and isclose(sl[1],b,rel_tol=10**(-6)) and isclose(sl[2],c,rel_tol=10**(-6)) and
               isclose(sl[3],d,rel_tol=10**(-6)) and isclose(sl[4],e,rel_tol=10**(-6)) and isclose(sl[5],f,rel_tol=10**(-6))) 
           for (a, b, c, d, e, f, _, _, _) in solsNoDup):
        solsNoDup.append(sl)
        
# Print the solutions
for sol in solsNoDup:
    sol[6] = atan2(sin(sol[6]),cos(sol[6]))
    sol[7] = atan2(sin(sol[7]),cos(sol[7]))
    if sol[6] < 0: sol[6] = sol[6]+2*pi
    if sol[7] < 0: sol[7] = sol[7]+2*pi
    print (f"Solution\n"
           f"========\n" 
           f"b=({sol[0]},{sol[1]},{sol[2]})\n"
           f"d=({sol[3]},{sol[4]},{sol[5]})\n"
           f"α={sol[6]}, β={sol[7]}, t={sol[8]}\n")


 Addendum - how we get the parameterization for $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ 
As requested, I'll explain how we got the parametrization for
$\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ by angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This is basically done by an application of rotation matrices.
We start by imagining a simple situation in which the turret rotates around the $z$ axis. Call that imagined vector $\vec{b}_0$, and assume it lies in the $z=0$ plane:
$$ \vec{b}_0 = r_1(\cos\alpha\hat{x} + \sin\alpha\hat{y}), $$
Now this position vector describes a circle that lies in a plane defined by the normal $\hat{z}$, so by two pure rotations with respect to the axes in 3D space we can change the plane it lies in to be the one defined by $\hat{n}$.
To make it more clear, inspect the diagram that describes the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$, which $\vec{n}$ makes with the $z$ and $x$ axis:

So the idea is that the same rotation which will rotate a vector from pointing straight upwards, to point at the new direction $\vec{n}$, will also change the orientation of the circle described by $\vec{b}_0$ accordingly and "tilt" its plane of motion so that its new normal will indeed become $\vec{n}$.
We see that we first need to rotate around the $y$ axis by an angle $\theta$. The matrix for that is:
$$ \mathbf{R}_y = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta \\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}, \tag{3} $$
and then after that, rotate around the $z$ axis by $\varphi$. The matrix that does that is:
$$ \mathbf{R}_z = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi & 0\\
\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{4}$$
now let's note the following relations that are clear from inspecting the above diagram:
\begin{align*}
 \cos\theta &= \frac{n_z}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2}} = n_z \\
 \sin\theta &= \frac{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2}} =
 \sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \\
 \cos\varphi &= \frac{n_x}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} \\
 \sin\varphi &= \frac{n_y}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} 
\end{align*}
So that our rotation matrices become:
\begin{align*} \mathbf{R}_y &= \begin{pmatrix} n_z & 0 &\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} & 0 & n_z \end{pmatrix} \\ \mathbf{R}_z &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}\begin{pmatrix} n_x & -n_y & 0\\
n_y & n_x & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
We want to apply $\mathbf{R}_y$ first and then $\mathbf{R}_z$ so we compute:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{R}_z \mathbf{R}_y &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}\begin{pmatrix} n_x & -n_y & 0\\
n_y & n_x & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} n_z & 0 & \sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} & 0 & n_z \end{pmatrix} 
\\&= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}\begin{pmatrix} n_x n_z & -n_y & n_x\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \\
n_y n_z & n_x & n_y\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \\
-(n_x^2+n_y^2) & 0 & n_z\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \end{pmatrix}
\tag{5}\end{align*}
Finally, we apply the above resulting matrix to $\vec{b}_0$ to obtain $\vec{b}$ :
\begin{align*} 
\vec{b} &= \mathbf{R}_z\mathbf{R}_y \vec{b}_0
\\&= \frac{r_1}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}\begin{pmatrix} n_x n_z & -n_y & n_x\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \\
n_y n_z & n_x & n_y\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \\
-(n_x^2+n_y^2) & 0 & n_z\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos\alpha \\ \sin\alpha \\ 0\end{pmatrix}   
\\ &\boxed{= \frac{r_1}{\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} \begin{pmatrix} n_x n_z \cos\alpha - n_y \sin\alpha \\
n_y n_z\cos\alpha + n_x\sin\alpha \\
-(n_x^2+n_y^2)\cos\alpha \end{pmatrix}}
\end{align*}
If we look closely at the meaning of the matrix product $\mathbf{R}_z \mathbf{R}_y$, we can figure out why the matrix is in fact undefined when $n_x=n_y=0$. Note that when that happens $\mathbf{R}_y$ collapses to the identity matrix, $\mathbf{R}_y=\mathbf{I}$. Which is fine, the $z$ axis makes no angle with respect to itself, so rotating around the $y$ axis by a zero angle does nothing.
However, now the second step hinges on $\varphi$ being defined. It is only after we tilt our imaginry $\hat{z}$ axis that the turret rotates around, that the angle $\varphi$ is even defined (refer to diagram again). So that in fact the matrix $\mathbf{R}_z$ itself becomes undefined when $\theta=0$. It's not that $\varphi=0$ when that occurs, but rather it is really undefined, for $\theta=0$ we can vary $\varphi$ without any effect, so it has no unique value, which leads to this issue.
But, this actually gives me an idea on how you can address this: if you apply the matrices separately, i.e first compute $\mathbf{R}_y$, check if it is the identity, and only if it isn't you apply $\mathbf{R}_z$, that's another way to sidestep this issue.
Now, as I hope is clear we do the same to parameterize $\vec{d}$ by the second angle $\beta$, with $\hat{b}$ now being the axis it revolves around.
So that's it, we end up having $\vec{b}$ as a function of $\alpha$, which is just a way to parameterize the angular position of the turret around its axis $\vec{n}$. Similarly, we have $\vec{d}$ as a function of $\beta$, which is a way to parameterize the angular position of the barrel around the sidelong "arm" of the turret, represented by vector $\vec{b}$. I hope that clarifies the issue!

Edit: a helpful tip in the comments from @Eli, is that you can use atan2, a two parameter function to obtain the angles $\varphi$ and $\theta$. Check with the documentation, but in some standard math libraries atan2 is defined for cases when the second parameter is $0$, and yet in other cases also for when they both are. See for example related SO question about the case of Python. So assuming you have access to such atan2, compute:
$$\theta = \mathrm{atan2}\left(\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2},n_z\right), \ \varphi = \mathrm{atan2}\left(n_y,n_x\right), $$
and use the output for constructing the matrices $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$ which give you $\vec{b}$ (similarly, for $\vec{d}$..).
A mathematical note of interest is that such a singularity is apparently inevitable in this kind of a parameterization, and it is closely related to the Hairy ball theorem. Quoting from Wikipedia:

A common problem in computer graphics is to generate a non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is orthogonal to a given non-zero vector. There is no single continuous function that can do this for all non-zero vector inputs. This is a corollary of the hairy ball theorem. To see this, consider the given vector as the radius of a sphere and note that finding a non-zero vector orthogonal to the given one is equivalent to finding a non-zero vector that is tangent to the surface of that sphere where it touches the radius. However, the hairy ball theorem says there exists no continuous function that can do this for every point on the sphere (equivalently, for every given vector).


 Update - alternative parameterization with a 'nicer' property 
If you twiddle a bit with the above Geogebra page, you'll note that varying $\alpha$ has the peculiar effect of changing the relative angle between the barrel (the green vector) and the plane of the turret (the brownish tilted plane).
This doesn't matter if we're just looking for any parameterization, and it still allows us to find correct solutions. But, if we want to use $\alpha$ and $\beta$ also for actually simulating and animating the motion of the turret and barrel in a game as the OP may, this would be a problem.
This bugged me a bit when I noticed it, so approaching it anew I found a parameterization for $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ that doesn't have this problem.
To do that, first we find two perpendicular vectors that lie in the plane of the turret. Call them $\hat{n}_\perp$ and $\hat{n}_\perp'$. Then after we do that, we can simply compute $\vec{b}$ as we would for plane circular motion with respect to that basis:
$$ \vec{b} = r_1\left(\cos\alpha\hat{n}_\perp + \sin\alpha\hat{n}_\perp'\right) $$
Similarly, $\vec{d}$ rotates in a plane spanned by $\vec{n}$ and another vector which is perpendicular to both $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{b}$ (this may require some mental effort to see.. or just use Geogebra ;)). So we can put $\vec{b}_\perp = \vec{n}\times\vec{b}$ and then write:
$$ \vec{d} = r_2\left(\cos\beta\hat{b}_\perp + \sin\beta\vec{n}\right),$$
where $\hat{b}_\perp$ is the normalized $\vec{b}_\perp$.
Now this post is already probably too long for me to include a detailed derivation that leads to the final form that $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ take. But of course since I had to test this, I've created a new Geogebra sheet and adapted the Python code to make use of this parameterization.
In both places you can inspect the expressions for $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ to see what changed. Interestingly, $\vec{b}$ doesn't change at all (apart from a trivial minus sign, which is just due to an arbitrary choice of the basis vectors that lie in the plane of the turret, and define $\vec{b}$'s plane of rotation) when computed by this approach, only $\vec{d}$ does!
This alternative approach is in some way much clearer, as we define the basis for the plane of rotation of each vector explicitly, so it makes some amount of sense that the mentioned "glitch" doesn't happen anymore, as you can verify also via the last Geogebra link.

Won't check it, but +1 so far for the in-depth details and interactive tools. I only suggest to use Jupyter, in the form of a gist, to share python scripts. I'll check the answer in the next few days, and the need for least square solution....and if some shorter simpler solution exists

Thanks a lot @basics! This is a fun problem and it would be nice to know how and whether the above can be improved on. Regarding the script sharing: I didn't manage to get along with Jupyter, but upon your suggestion I've now included a permalink to the script in SageCell, check out the latest edit. For some reason, I was sure it won't be able to import scipy, but it works just fine, so that should do as well! :)

try to start working with jupyter. Available with Colab with just a Google account. Seamlessly deployable as a jupyter book as a website from github or gitlab. Very powerful tool, IMHO

@Amit why in  your example  $~\vec b\cdot\vec n~\ne 0~$?

@Eli you're right, I must have messed up somewhere when I copied the values from Geogebra... essentially the guess value for $\vec{b}$ isn't supposed to matter, because the solver should be able to converge on a solution anyway, perhaps slower and it won't be the one closest to the current configuration. So thanks, I'll address that along with some more annoying issue I found out, I have a normalization issue with $\vec{d}$, the units are all wrong as one can also notice...

@Eli Fixed now. Thank you! (the dot product won't be exactly zero still of course, but as close as it gets considering I'm copy & pasting floating point values from Geogebra, where I set up the initial conditions, so it can be demonstrated too in the link... in Geogebra the dot product vanishes precisely ;) )

Thank you for the thorough answer! Two questions: How did you get the first rotation equations (and what other vectors are the angles in relation to)?
Was there a reason you didn't use the second optimization, that is, rotating $\vec{n}$ upright?

@ThomasB. You're welcome! The rotation equations are just a result of applying a rotation matrix to a parameterized circular trajectory. Essentially, if you start from $r_1(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha,0)$, as in a parameterized circle around the $z$ axis in the $z=0$ plane, and rotate it by two angles that correspond to two directional cosines that $\vec{n}$ makes with the coordinate system, you'll get the expression for $\vec{b}$. Then having done that, do the same for $\vec{d}$ with respect to $\vec{b}$.

About rotating $\vec{n}$ upright, I did start from that approach. Then I realized you don't really gain anything apart from making the kinematic equations more complicated, because the passive coordinate rotation that would make $\vec{n}$ upright is closely related to the active rotation I just described which takes the circle from traversing around $\hat{z}$ to traversing around $\vec{n}$. Yet we would still have to pay in the form of a more complicated $\vec{g}$ vector, so I didn't end up using that approach. I'm sure it's doable but see no benefit to it.

@Amit to avoid singularity you can use this equations for the transformation matrix. $~\phi=\arctan (ny,nx),~\theta=\arctan(nz,\sqrt{nx^2+ny^2})$  where this arctan(….) is valid from zero to $~2\pi$

@Eli Thanks a lot, this can be helpful and I'll add a note about it in the answer. However I think that counts as a programmatic trick right? strictly speaking, $\arctan(0,0)$ should be undefined, but in some software libraries it is common to have it return $0$ in that case. I dug a little bit deeper into this, the fact we can't parameterize the orientation without at least one singularity is closely related to the hairy ball theorem -- the link is to a specific section that describes the exact issue!

@Eli thanks for reviewing but I had to rollback your edit -- atan2(y,x) by convention computes to $\arctan(y/x)$. The argument order was correct, my $\theta$ has the same convention as we use in the transformation from cartesian to spherical coordinates.

@Amit I prefer to use my 7 equations plus $~\vec d\cdot\vec d-r_2^2=0~$  , eight scalar equations for 7 unknows  and applying the LS numerical method

@Eli yes that would seem to do just as well. I thought that the parameterization by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would also give some more physical insight into this problem, as it is easier to understand what happens geometrically when we reduce the number of free variables to just 3, $\alpha$,$\beta$,$t$.

To solve your  problem , you need 6  equations for the 3 components of the vector $~\vec d~$ , the 3 components of the vector $~\vec b~$, and 1 equation for the target time $~t_T~$, together 7 scalar  equations.
which are
$$ \vec b\cdot \vec n=0\\
 \vec d\cdot \vec b=0\\
 \vec b\cdot\vec b-r_1^2=0\\
\vec d\cdot\vec d-r_2^2=0\\
\vec b+\vec d+\frac{v_0}{r_2}\,\vec d\,t_T+\frac 12 \vec g\,t_T^2-\vec T=0$$
we have 7 equations for the unknowns $~b_x~,b_y~,b_z,~d_x~,d_y~,d_z~,t_T$
with @Amit example
$$\vec n= \left[ \begin {array}{c}  0.364\\  0.543
\\  0.7567397175\end {array} \right] \quad,
\vec T=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 2\\  -3
\\  3.5\end {array} \right] 
\quad,
v_0=9\quad, 
r2 = 2.5\quad,
r1 = 2
$$
$$$$
$$ \vec d=\left[ \begin {array}{c}  0.07964319891\\  -
 1.207400184\\   2.187656682\end {array} \right]
\quad,
\vec b= \left[ \begin {array}{c}  1.844729378\\  -
 0.6460792696\\ - 0.4237394219\end {array} \right] \quad,
t_T=0.2637716425e0$$
Notice
the solution fulfilled always  the equation $~ \vec d\,\cdot [(\vec T-\vec b)\times \vec g]=0~$


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
